# AttributeError error in pytest when trying to make an orm request

Tags: sqlalchemy, pytest, python-asyncio, fastapi, pytest-asyncio

I want to check the data that I receive from the FastAPI handle, when I try to make an orm request I get an error. I'm using Pytest-asyncio

I checked the session, the database is fine with them

```
@pytest.fixture
async def db():
    async with async_session_maker() as session:
        yield session


app.dependency_overrides[db] = db


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')
async def prepare_db():
    async with test_engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(metadata.create_all)
    yield
    async with test_engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(metadata.drop_all)


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def event_loop(request):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()


client = TestClient(app)


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
async def ac():
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as ac:
        yield ac

#test file
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_menu(ac: AsyncClient, db):
    menu_id = id_dict['menu_id']
    menu = await db.get(Menu, menu_id)
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.

Comment: 10-20 errors, start is ``` ..\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\session.py:602: in get
    return await greenlet_spawn( ```
last ``` ..\venv\Lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connection.py:350: in execute
    result = await self._protocol.query(query, timeout)```( i can't edit with full traceback)

Comment: What do you mean by: " i can't edit with full traceback"? Just copy and paste your full traceback into your question (and enclose it in code markers, e.g. triple backticks).

Comment: if i do this, im need more comment without text

Comment: Still not sure what you mean - you need to edit the question, not write a comment.